# Upgrading to Corda 4

Tags: corda

I'm following the documentation on how to upgrade apps to Corda 4 and I wonder why the `corda_release_version` is set to `5.0-SNAPSHOT` in the Gradle build file.

Answer (score 2):

In the docs page here:

https://docs.corda.net/app-upgrade-notes.html

the version appears to be 4.0 as expected. Where do you see a reference to 5.0-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: That page is generated automatically from git master - you can see the branch/version name at the top left. So it reflects whatever the current in progress version is. To read the docs for the current version, just use docs.corda.net without the /head